# Get sound amplitude in Python with SL4A

Tags: android, python, audio, sl4a, amplitude

I want to record sound for 1 second using a Python written app for SL4A and then find the max amplitude of the sound.

Is there any part of the SL4A API I can use or part of the Python APIs that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can record using the MediaRecorderFacade

http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/MediaRecorderFacade.html

you can try this

```
droid.recorderStartMicrophone("/sdcard/myfile.wav")
sleep(1)
droid.recorderStop()
```

I hope there is a module to do some treatment on wave file in python.

If you find one you can compile and install.

Here is a doc to do it: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_install_other_Python_modules?